# Probability of drawing an ace on or before ninth card

Tags: probability

> What is the probability of drawing an ace on or before the ninth card drawn?

I could grind out the following computation $$\frac{4}{52}\; +\; \frac{\left( 48\cdot4 \right)}{\left( 52\cdot51 \right)}\; +\; \frac{\left( 48\cdot47\cdot4 \right)}{\left( 52\cdot51\cdot50 \right)}\; ...\; +\; \frac{\left( 
\; 48\cdot47\cdot46\cdot45\cdot44\cdot43\cdot42\cdot41\cdot4 \right)}{\left( 52\cdot51\cdot50\cdot49\cdot48\cdot47\cdot46\cdot45\cdot44 \right)}$$

but that would take a lot of time. Is there an easier way to approach the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about the complement. What is the probability that an ace is drawn NOT in the first nine cards?
$$\frac{48}{52}*\frac{47}{51}*\frac{47}{51}*...*\frac{40}{44}$$
Now the probability that an ace is drawn in the first nine cards is just $1$ minus that....SOOOO

$$1-\frac{48!/39!}{52!/43!}$$

Answer (score 0):

The chance of not drawing an ace is to have the first nine cards come from the non-aces.  How many ways are there to select nine cards out of the non-aces?  Divide by the number of ways to select nine cards.  Subtract from 1.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're drawing cards from a shuffled standard deck (of 52) without repetition.
 $$1 - \frac{\,^{48}P_9}{\,^{52}P_9} = 1- \frac{48!\;43!}{52!\;39!} = \frac{4209}{7735}$$

That is, the complement of the probability of not drawing an ace in the first nine cards.